# Excel Custom data validation Formula

Tags: excel

I have an Excel file that I am trying to add validation to stop the user if the conditions are not Met, below is my formula however, that is not returning the expected results:

```
=IF(A1="",TRUE,IF((B1*5)>A2,True,FALSE))
```

Here is what I am trying to accomplish:

```
 1) If A1 is Blank, then don't allow the user to enter anything in A2
 2) The Max the user can enter in A2 is 5 times the value in A1.
 up.
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try a Custom validation formula of:

```
=AND(COUNT(A1),A2<=5*A1)
```

and ensure "Ignore blank" is not checked.

Comment: I always forget that pesky check box.

Comment: nope, I have moved on to sql databases, and use code to validate entries. And most the excel sheets I design I design for myself.